# Delete specific part of string

Tags: string, inno-setup, pascal

I'm using Pascal scripting to return a string based on a registry entry but I need to delete a specific part of that string.

Here's the current code:

```
function GetDirName(Value: string): string;
var          
  InstallPath: string;
begin
  // initialize default path, which will be returned when the following registry
  // key queries fail due to missing keys or for some different reason
  Result := '{pf}\LucasArts\Star Wars Battlefront II\RegistryFailed';
  // query the first registry value; if this succeeds, return the obtained value
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\LucasArts\Star Wars Battlefront II\1.0', 'ExePath', InstallPath) then
    Result := InstallPath
  // otherwise the first registry key query failed, so...
  else
  // query the second registry value; if it succeeds, return the obtained value
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\LucasArts\Star Wars Battlefront II\1.0', 'ExePath', InstallPath) then
    Result := InstallPath
end;
```

The part that I need to remove from the returned string is *\BattlefrontII.exe* and it is always located at the very end of the string.

Example of what the returned string currently is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\LucasArts\Star Wars Battlefront II\GameData\BattlefrontII.exe`

Example of what I need the returned string to look more-or-less like: `C:\Program Files (x86)\LucasArts\Star Wars Battlefront II\GameData`

Any help is appreciated.

P.S. I am entirely new to Pascal; I'm only using it to compile an installer using Inno Setup Compiler

Comment: OT: never query explicitly `Wow6432Node` registry path. Instead use a direct path and `HKLM32` or `HKLM64` for root keys. Their descriptions you can find in the [`[Registry]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection) section.

Comment: Any reason for this? (Note: My installer is only reading registry entries, not writing any.)

Comment: It's easier for you to maintain but what's more important is that you'll be using system redirector which will redirect you to the right registry view path. Who knows, maybe Microsoft decide to rename `Wow6432Node` to `Wow1234Node` which will be meant as a redirection node, and since that time you'll be out of luck with your hardcode.

Comment: I've reverted your edit, as you modified the question being asked after you received an answer to the original. Please don't do that; it invalidates previous answers, can make the person who answered look pretty foolish, and in some cases can cost them reputation, none of which is very nice to those spending time trying to help you. If you have a new question, post a new question."I've changed my code (it's now this new code) and it still doesn't work. It now has this different problem." is a new question. This is not "evolve my code" - it's question and answer.

Comment: One would expect the "EDIT:" bit to render that all nil, but whatever I guess. My bad. Not used to this style of forums. As for my issue, I believe the problem is solved. Will let you know (with a new question :D) if issues persist. HUGE thanks to you all. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like what you want is [`ExtractFilePath`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extractfilepath):

```
function ExtractFilePath(const FileName: string): String;
```

> Description: Extracts the drive and directory parts of the given file
>   name. The resulting string is the leftmost characters of FileName, up
>   to and including the colon or backslash that separates the path
>   information from the name and extension. The resulting string is empty
>   if FileName contains no drive and directory parts.

See the [list of functions](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptfunctions) for more useful stuff.

In your case, you could put this:

```
Result := ExtractFilePath(Result);
```

At the end of your function.

*Edit*: to be extra explicit:

```
function GetDirName(const Value: string): string;
var          
  InstallPath: string;
begin
  // initialize default path, which will be returned when the following registry
  // key queries fail due to missing keys or for some different reason
  Result := ExpandConstant('{pf}\LucasArts\Star Wars Battlefront II\RegistryFailed');
  // query the first registry value; if this succeeds, return the obtained value
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\LucasArts\Star Wars Battlefront II\1.0', 'ExePath', InstallPath) then
    Result := InstallPath  
  // otherwise the first registry key query failed, so...
  else
  // query the second registry value; if it succeeds, return the obtained value
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\LucasArts\Star Wars Battlefront II\1.0', 'ExePath', InstallPath) then
    Result := InstallPath;

  // return only the path
  Result := ExtractFilePath(Result);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. But how exactly would I implement this? (Normally I'd be able to figure this kind of thing out myself but I'm still extremely new to the syntax and language itself.)

Comment: It's fairly simple. Edited.

Comment: >implying I know what I am doing in the very least --- No but um, I still don't understand; putting that at the end of my function brings up an error while compiling. One sec while I try a few things.

Comment: >nowhere near 4chan
>implying things at me -- edited to be extra explicit :)

Comment: @user3639133, you were close :-) You were just missing `;` at the end of the statement which prevented you from compiling.